# GNU tar man-page mysterious references to METHOD='replace' and METHOD='system'

Tags: tar, atime

My tar (GNU tar 1.28) man-page lists the --atime-preserve option, which applies to the time a  file is added to the tarball.
The full explanation reads thus:

```
 --atime-preserve
       preserve access times on dumped files, either by restoring the times after reading (METHOD='replace'; default) or by not setting
       the times in the first place (METHOD='system')
```

However, what is exactly meant by METHOD='replace' and METHOD='system' remains unexplained.
Can anyone shed a light on this?

Answer (score 1):

They're simply the values of that option. The [online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC42) (and the `info` docs as well - check `info tar 'Option Summary'`) make it clearer:

> `--atime-preserve`
>   `--atime-preserve=replace`
>   `--atime-preserve=system`
>
> Attempt to preserve the access time of files when reading them. This
>   option currently is effective only on files that you own, unless you
>   have superuser privileges.
>
> `--atime-preserve=replace` remembers the access time of a file before
>   reading it, and then restores the access time afterwards. This may
>   cause problems if other programs are reading the file at the same
>   time, as the times of their accesses will be lost. On most platforms
>   restoring the access time also requires tar to restore the data
>   modification time too, so this option may also cause problems if other
>   programs are writing the file at the same time (tar attempts to detect
>   this situation, but cannot do so reliably due to race conditions).
>   Worse, on most platforms restoring the access time also updates the
>   status change time, which means that this option is incompatible with
>   incremental backups.
>
> `--atime-preserve=system` avoids changing time stamps on files,
>   without interfering with time stamp updates caused by other programs,
>   so it works better with incremental backups. However, it requires a
>   special `O_NOATIME` option from the underlying operating and file
>   system implementation, and it also requires that searching directories
>   does not update their access times. As of this writing (November 2005)
>   this works only with Linux, and only with Linux kernels 2.6.8 and
>   later. Worse, there is currently no reliable way to know whether this
>   feature actually works. Sometimes tar knows that it does not work, and
>   if you use `--atime-preserve=system` then tar complains and exits
>   right away. But other times tar might think that the option works when
>   it actually does not.

Comment: Thanks! Very informative.